# Manage files in geodatabase for ArcPy loop?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have a piece of code consisting of hundreds of lines that contain multiple processes (snapping, feature to polygon, erase, etc.) and I am going to make a `for loop` that will take care of many files that can be found in a geodatabase.

How to keep track of all the files and their copies in the cases where you need to maintain copies in operations like `Snap_edit` where it modifies the original and use only the files needed for the processes that will follow?

It looks chaotic and would like to hear ideas about how to manage the files (original files, copies, outputs of mid-processes etc.) in the geodatabase so they can be used for the processes in a for loop.

Comment: What kind of naming conventions are you using to keep track of the different stages?